# Calling a constructor from the body of another constructor

Tags: c++

The typical way (and the only one widely used) to delegate some part of the object initialization to another constructor is to call it using the initializer list, like so:

```
class Window
{
  Window(int a);
  Window(int a, void *b);
  Window(string a);

  Window(double a, double b) : Window((int) (a + b))
  {
  }
};
```

But sometimes there is a necessity to do some prep work or branch constructor calls.

Is this how it should be done?

```
class Window
{
  Window(int a);
  Window(int a, void *b);
  Window(string a);

  Window(double a, double b)
  {
    if (a * b == 0.0)
    {
      Window("ZERO");
    }
    else if (a * b > 100.0)
    {
      Window((int) (a + b), x);
    }
    else
    {
      Window((int) (a + b));
    }
  }
};
```

I have never seen anything like this; this is just my guess of how it could look (which appears to be working).

Are there any side effects or any undefined behavior to calling other constructors from the constructor body (and not from the initializer list)?

@Edit: I'm including the code I'm having a problem with below. Basically, I have an object that is a container for some data, and I store it in a `std::map<CString, ValueContainer>`. I employ a copy constructor, and an overloaded assignment operator. The insertion works fine when I add an instance to the map using the `[]` operator, but it doesn't when I use the `insert_or_assign` method, because it uses the copy constructor (which uses the branching that is the problem here). Here's a simplification of the class.

```
class ValueContainer
{
  ValueContainer(const VOID *p_data, ULONG p_size)
  {
    if (p_data != NULL)
    {
      if (p_size > 0)
      {
        if (p_size <= sizeof(shortData))
        {
          memcpy(shortData, p_data, p_size);
        }
        else
        {
          longData = new BYTE[p_size];

          memcpy(longData, p_data, p_size);
        }
      }

      hasValue = TRUE;
      size = p_size;
    }
    else
    {
      hasValue = FALSE;
      size = 0;
    }
  }

  ValueContainer(const ValueContainer &p_value)
  {
    if (p_value.HasValue())
    {
      if (p_value.size <= sizeof(shortData))
      {
        ValueContainer(p_value.shortData, p_value.size);
      }
      else
      {
        ValueContainer(p_value.longData, p_value.size);
      }
    }
    else
    {
      ValueContainer();
    }
  }

  ValueContainer(VOID) : ValueContainer(NULL, 0)
  {
  }

  ValueContainer &operator =(const ValueContainer &p_value);
  {
    if (p_value.hasValue)
    {
      if (p_value.size <= sizeof(shortData))
      {
        if (longData != NULL)
        {
          free(longData);

          longData = NULL;
        }

        memcpy(shortData, p_value.shortData, p_value.size);
      }
      else
      {
        if (p_value.size > size)
        {
          longData = (BYTE *) realloc(longData, p_value.size);
        }

        memcpy(longData, p_value.longData, p_value.size);
      }

      hasValue = TRUE;
      size = p_value.size;
    }
    else
    {
      if (longData != NULL)
      {
        free(longData);

        longData = NULL;
      }

      hasValue = FALSE;
      size = 0;
    }

    return *this;
  }

private:
  BYTE  shortData[16];
  BYTE *longData = NULL;
  BOOL  hasValue;
  ULONG size;
}
```

Comment: This will not do what you want: the statements in the constructor body create temporary variables of the same type `Window`, which are then immediately discarded, and the members of the object being constructed are still in their default-initialized state.

Comment: **−1** You should ask a new question with your actual `ValueContainer` problem, because the `Window` analogy in the main question is nothing like it. A reasonable answer to that doesn't apply to your problem.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Actually, the posted answers apply to my problem, and solve it.

Comment: @JulSe: I fail to see that they do.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Yes, they use the artificial example I posted originally (for which I am really sorry; didn't mean to offend anyone), but they solved my problem, because it is still the same, no matter if I strip down my code from unnecessary information or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first example, this might be the way it can be done:

```
class Window
{
private:
    void constructor_method(int a);
    void constructor_method(int a, void *b);
    void constructor_method(string a);

public:
  Window(int a) {
      constructor_method(a);
  }
  Window(int a, void *b) {
      constructor_method(a, b);
  }
  Window(string a) {
      constructor_method(a);
  }

  Window(double a, double b)
  {
    if (a * b == 0.0)
    {
        constructor_method("ZERO");
    }
    else if (a * b > 100.0)
    {
        constructor_method((int) (a + b), x);
    }
    else
    {
        constructor_method((int) (a + b));
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Maybe - this assumes it's possible and reasonably cheap to default construct all base classes and members.

Answer (score 2):

I think the short answer to this question is "simplify your code."  But if that's not an option, I think the next best alternative is a factory method:

```
class Window
{
private:
    Window(int a);
    Window(int a, void *b);
    Window(string a);

public:
    static Window Create(double a, double b)
    {
        if (a * b == 0.0)
        {
            return Window("ZERO");
        }
        else if (a * b > 100.0)
        {
            return Window((int) (a + b), x);
        }
        else
        {
            return Window((int) (a + b));
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Actually, yours and @KorelK 's solutions are very clever, and solve the problem nicely :) I might go for extracting the assignment portion to a separate ``SetValue(const VOID *, ULONG)`` method. Apparently, I didn't catch that what I did was actually creating a new instance of the class rather than calling a constructor (I'm still not quite at home with C++, coming from C# and Java).